# Is there a sense in which two gauge connections are topologically equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, connections, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

We say that manifolds $M$ and $N$ are topologically equivalent iff there exists a homeomorphism between them. Is there are similar notion for gauge connections? I.e. is there a sense in which two gauge connections are topologically equivalent?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by if two connections are topologically equivalent but Chern Weil theory comes to mind, which computes topological invariants of vector and principal bundles from the curvature form of a connection. Otherwise if you're interested in which connections are equivalent up to gauge then it would be $A\sim g\cdot A=g^{-1}A+g^{-1}dg$ where $A$ are the connection components and $g$ is in the gauge group.

Comment: @BaselJ. I see. So one can speak of the topology of the underlying bundle P, and use any gauge connection on P as a means of calculating the topological invariants of P (similar to how one can equip a smooth manifold with a metric, and use the metric to compute smooth or topological invariants of the manifold).

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: @BaselJ. What do you think of the following fact though: a principle $SU(N)$ bundle over $S^3$ is trivial; However, a global section of the bundle, $\Omega(x)$, has a topological winding number given by $\int d^3x ~\epsilon^{ijk}(\Omega^{-1}\partial_i\Omega ~\Omega^{-1}\partial_j\Omega ~\Omega^{-1}\partial_k\Omega)$. Does the existence of sections with non-zero winding number have anything to do with the topology of the bundle?